# In SOSL Query I want to retrieve the records from the object which is given in custom settings?

Tags: sosl

Here is my code:

```
public with sharing class SOSLController {
    public string srchobj {get; set;}


    public Map<String, EventPreferences__c> mapEventPref;
    public EventPreferences__c EvntPrefLists {get; set;}

    public String searchStr {get; set;}
    public SOSLController() {

        mapEventPref = EventPreferences__c.getAll();
        EvntPrefLists = mapEventPref.values();
        srchobj = EvntPrefLists.CustomSearchObject__c;

    }

    public void soslDemo_method() {
        if (searchStr.length() > 1) {
            String searchStr1 = '*' + searchStr + '*';
            String searchQuery = 'FIND \'' + searchStr1 + '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING srchobj(Id,Name,type),Contact(name,email),Opportunity(name,StageName)';
            List<List <sObject>> searchList = search.query(searchQuery);
        }
    }
}
```

It is showing the following error:

> System.QueryException: sObject type 'srchobj' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

`String searchQuery = 'FIND \'' + searchStr1 + '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING '+ srchobj + '(Id,Name,type),Contact(name,email),Opportunity(name,StageName)';`